# How to change an existing user's password?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to change the password of an existing user with Ansible, but only if the user is already present. I do not want to create any new users. Is there any good way?

```
vars:
myusers:
  - { name: 'user1', update_pass: 'passwd' }
  - { name: 'user2', update_pass: 'passwd' }
  - { name: 'user3', update_pass: 'passwd' }  

tasks:
- name: check exist
  shell: /usr/sbin/usermod {{ item.name }}
  with_items: myusers
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc not in [6,2]
  changed_when: result.rc != 6

- name: change passwd
  user: name={{ item.name }} password={{ item.update_pass  }} update_password=always
  when: result|changed
  with_items: myusers
```

Comment: you can use the approach you have started.   You'll just need to iterate over the results variable in your "change passwd" task which will contain the value of item for each run of the shell command.  You'll also need to to add "ignore_results" to your "check exists" task so the playbook doesn't terminate

Comment: @Petro026 thank you for comment. Now, I use ansible option "`--extra-vars:@userX.yml`" and "for loop --extra-vars" using local shell command. "ignore_results" in the task, I do not understand insert line.....Sorry, It is ansible beginner, but does it appear in an online document?

Answer (score 0):

```
vars_prompt:
- name: user_name
prompt: Enter the user name for password reset
private: no
- name: pass
prompt: Enter the password
tasks:
- name: Change {{ user_name }}  password
user: name={{ user_name }} password={{ pass|password_hash('sha512') }} update_password=always
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
vars:
myusers:
  - { name: 'user1', update_pass: 'passwd' }
  - { name: 'user2', update_pass: 'passwd' }
  - { name: 'user3', update_pass: 'passwd' } 

# Contents of passwd will be stored in ansible_facts.getent_passwd as a dict
- name: Determine local user accounts
  getent:
    database: passwd

# Update password if user account is found in /etc/passwd
- name: change passwd
  user: name={{ item.name }} password={{ item.update_pass  }} update_password=always
  with_items: myusers
  when: item in ansible_facts.getent_passwd
```